# Is there such a being as 'Dark Multiverse' Darkseid?

Tags: dc, batman, parallel-universe

I've recently been reading DC Comic's Dark Multiverse and I have been wondering just how the Dark Universe interacts with the Fourth World.

In Dark Knights Metal

> Darkseid is still a baby, and Batman threatens to "use him." Later in the series, after Earth is pulled below the "Cosmic Membrane" we see an adult Darkseid fighting against the remaining heroes.

We know that version differs from the "real" version because

> Grail has yet to help Darkseid kill Zeus to regain his power. Therefore, the original version is still an infant.

Additionally, in Tales of the Dark Multiverse: Blackest Night

> Darkseid falls under the power of the Black Lanterns. He is killed (?) by the end when the entire universe is remade in the image of Lobo. Is this yet a third Darkseid, or merely an avatar the genuine article abandoned after this universe fell to the dark?

I know that the Fourth World is meant to exist outside the 52 universes, as evidenced by the map Kendra Sauders has in Dark Knights Metal. But does the Fourth World also have 'dark' counterpart? As Kendra put it, is there a Fourth World 'on the back of the map?'

Answer (score 1):

So after some thought, I think I figured it out. I'm not going accept my own answer though, in case someone else knows better.

Firstly, I think the answer is **yes** there is a Dark Multiverse Darkseid.

Here's what I think happened. In the Dark Multiverse's Final Crisis

> Darkseid is killed, just like his light universe counterpart.

This is why, in Tales of The Dark Multiverse: Blackest Night

> He falls under Nekron's influence. He's dead. At the end of these events, he's truly dead.

After this, I suspect that the Dark Multiverse has a Flashpoint, like the Light Multiverse (or perhaps, Barry messed with the Timeline enough that):

> Dark Multiverse Darkseid is resurrected by Flashpoint, just as his light version counterpart was in the New 52.

In any case, the universes diverge: in the Dark Multiverse,

> The Anti-Monitor is unable to kill Darkseid. Perhaps this is because Grail refuses to assist the Anti-Monitor, or the Dark Multiverse version of Darkseid kills Grail on sight, I don't know. Bottom line: Darkseid isn't killed.

This explains why, in Dark Nights Metal:

> The Light Universe Darkseid is an infant, while the Dark Multiverse Darkseid is alive and an adult.

Darkseid is.